# NullPointerException while creating security handler for decryption : error while extracting text from PDF using pdfbox

Tags: android, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox library to create PDFs. and also using PDFBox for extracting text and images from pdf.

I am using PDFBox version 1.8.10.1.

The problem is, when I try to extract text from password protected PDF, even though the password is correct, it shows me the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Error (NullPointerException) while creating security handler for decryption

```
public class PdfTextExtractor extends AsyncTask<File,String,String>{

    private String password;
    private OnTextExtractedListener onTextExtractedListener;

    public PdfTextExtractor(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addOnTextExtracted(OnTextExtractedListener onTextExtractedListener){
        this.onTextExtractedListener=onTextExtractedListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... files) {
        File targetFile=files[0];

        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
        PDDocument pdDoc;
        COSDocument cosDoc;

        try {
            Log.e("password",password);
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(targetFile, "r"),password);
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            System.out.println(parsedText);

            return parsedText;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String extractedText) {
        super.onPostExecute(extractedText);
        if(onTextExtractedListener!=null)
            onTextExtractedListener.onTextExtracted(extractedText);
    }

    public interface OnTextExtractedListener{
        void onTextExtracted(String extractedText);
    }
}
```

The Exception StackTrace:

> 05-13 11:00:28.090 19049-20403/com.veridocofflineverification.android W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Error (NullPointerException) while creating security handler for decryption
>   05-13 11:00:28.097 19049-20403/com.veridocofflineverification.android W/System.err:     at com.f.c.g.g.F(PDFParser.java:323)
>           at com.f.c.g.g.D(PDFParser.java:230)
>           at com.f.c.g.g.E(PDFParser.java:264)
>           at com.veridocofflineverification.android.e.a.c.a(PdfTextExtractor.java:46)
>           at com.veridocofflineverification.android.e.a.c.doInBackground(PdfTextExtractor.java:17)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>   05-13 11:00:28.098 19049-20403/com.veridocofflineverification.android W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
>           at com.f.c.i.c.s.a(StandardSecurityHandler.java:291)
>           at com.f.c.i.c.s.a(StandardSecurityHandler.java:245)
>           at com.f.c.g.g.F(PDFParser.java:313)
>           ... 10 more

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

**Edit**

while searching for the solution, I found the link. in [this](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2347) link, they said following solution:

> so the encryption item is COSNull which is not the same as "null" when
>   using getItem(). So the solution is to use getDictionaryObject()
>   instead, because it checks for COSNull. This method is already used
>   elsewhere in PDFBox to get /Encrypt.

But I did not understand what to do and how to do !? Please help me.

Comment: I can't help because this is PDFBox for Android, but I'd recommend you to edit your question: mention the version, share the file, and include more of the stack trace. It would also be interesting whether the file opens with desktop PDFBox. (try PDFDebugger)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've edited question.

Comment: The issue has been resolved for now (temporary bases). I reduced the key size to 128 while generating and encrypting the pdf. and now it is working.

Comment: AES256 encryption / decryption isn't supported in the 1.8 desktop version, on which PDFBox for Android is mostly based. You could try a development version: https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/117

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for the information. It helped.